# I get java.lang.RuntimeException when trying to cast Object to GoogleMap using AsyncTask<>

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I get this message in LogCat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:330)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:255)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:776)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
```

using Kotlin in android studio

```
class GetDirectionsData : AsyncTask<Any?, String, String>() {

    internal var mMap: GoogleMap? = null
    internal var url: String = ""
    internal var googleDirectionsData: String = ""
    internal var duration: String? = null
    internal var distance: String? = null
    internal var latLng: LatLng? = null

    override fun doInBackground(vararg objects: Any?): String {
        mMap = objects[0] as GoogleMap
        url = objects[1] as String
        latLng = objects[2] as LatLng


        val downloadUrl = DownloadUrl()
        try {
            googleDirectionsData = downloadUrl.readUrl(url)
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return googleDirectionsData
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(s: String) {

        val directionsList: Array<String>
        val parser = DataParser()
        directionsList = parser.parseDirections(s)
        displayDirection(directionsList)

    }

    fun displayDirection(directionsList: Array<String>) {

        val count = directionsList.size
        for (i in 0 until count) {
            val options = PolylineOptions()
            options.color(Color.RED)
            options.width(10f)
            options.addAll(PolyUtil.decode(directionsList[i]))

            mMap?.addPolyline(options)
        }
    }
} .   //I call it from Activity Like this:val dataTransfer = arrayOfNulls<Any>(3)
    var url:String = getDirectionsUrl()
    var getDirectionsData = GetDirectionsData()
    dataTransfer[0] = mGoogleMap
    dataTransfer[1] = url
    dataTransfer[2] = LatLng(mDestinationlatLng!!.latitude, mDestinationlatLng!!.longitude)
    getDirectionsData.execute(dataTransfer)
```

Comment: This means your first argument is an `Object[]`. Are you sure you're sending the parameters correctly?

Comment: @riadrifai Yes I send it correctly after cursor reach **mMap = objects[0] as GoogleMap**. app through Exception.

Comment: Can you show the code of how you're calling the task and what you're sending?

Comment: val dataTransfer = arrayOfNulls<Any>(3) . 
        var url:String = getDirectionsUrl() . 
        var getDirectionsData = GetDirectionsData() . 
        dataTransfer[0] = mGoogleMap . 
        dataTransfer[1] = url . 
        dataTransfer[2] = LatLng(mDestinationlatLng!!.latitude, 
 mDestinationlatLng!!.longitude)
        getDirectionsData.execute(dataTransfer) .

Comment: @riadrifai check I updated the code.

Comment: Check Sky's updated answer. It has the solution. You're sending an array of objects and the first parameter. You should send them separately instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are sending the wrong param in `object[0]`

Change your implementation like this and check your params.

```
if(objects[0] is GoogleMap)
   mMap = objects[0] as GoogleMap
if(objects[1] is String)
   url = objects[1] as String
if(objects[2] is LatLng)
   latLng = objects[2] as LatLng
```

Change your code like this:

```
 var getDirectionsData = GetDirectionsData()
 getDirectionsData.execute(mGoogleMap,url,LatLng(mDestinationlatLng!!.latitude, mDestinationlatLng!!.longitude))
```

Comment: The app not accessing to first IF and access to second IF but through an error **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1**